# What's the correct way to impliment a "pluralize" command in LaTeX?

Tags: plural

If it matters, I'm using pdflatex.

I'm trying to write a command that does the following. This isn't homework, just something that would make my life easier. So alternatives to what I have are fine, and if there's a built-in command for this, that's also great.

My command (I'll call it `\pluralize{num}{singular}{plural}`) will take a number as the first argument, and the singular form + plural form of a word as the second/third arguments. Then, it will choose which form of the word to use based on the value of the first argument.

Here's what I came up with:

```latex
\newcommand{\pluralize}[3]{#1 \ifnum#1=1 #2\else #3\fi}
```

Here's a (working) MCVE of it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\pluralize}[3]{#1 \ifnum#1=1 #2\else #3\fi}

\begin{document}
    You have \pluralize{1}{item}{items}.
    
    You have \pluralize{2}{item}{items}.
\end{document}
```

which produces:

> You have 1 item.
>
> You have 2 items.

While that works, I'm still fairly new to LaTeX, so I'm wondering if (a) my `\pluralize` command can be improved or (b) if there's an existing command that already does that.

Comment: `\ifthenelse{#1=1}{#2}{#3}` is a little bit more robust with regards to nested `\if`. (requires `\usepackage{ifthen}`)

Comment: having to use the number and both forms on every instance looks like making work and not ensuring consistency, I would instead define a declaration form so you have `\DeclarePluralCommand\itm{item}{items}`  .... `you have \itm{1}`  ... `you have \itm{2}`