# Add a plural sign depending on the number of items

Tags: macros, pdftex, conditionals, ifthenelse, value

I'd like to add a plural sign (say a 's') when needed. My current use case is for pluralizing a noun based on the number of pages in a document but I could also count oranges and bananas down the road.

Based on this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/681062/whats-the-correct-way-to-impliment-a-pluralize-command-in-latex), I tried to write the following somewhat simplified command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pageslts}

\newcommand{\pls}[1]{\ifnum#1>1 s\fi}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
There are currently \lastpageref{LastPages} page\pls{\value{LastPages}} in this manuscript.

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I have a `! Missing number, treated as zero.` error. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `refcount`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage{refcount}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\pls}{%
  There \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{LastPages}>1 are \else is \fi
  currently \lastpageref{LastPages} page\ifnum\getpagerefnumber{LastPages}>1 s\fi
  \ in this manuscript.
}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pls

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Note that `\pagenumbering` is necessary as stated in the manual of `pageslts`.

[image]

If you remove the `\lipsum[1-20]` line you get

[image]

For a generic “add ‘a’ for plural” command, I suggest

```
\newcommand{\pls}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1>1 s\fi
}
```

which you can call as

```
\pls{\getpagerefnumber{LastPages}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I kept my \pls command as it was and used it with \getpagrefnumber{LastPages}.

Comment: @greendiod Yes, of course. I added it.